# How to open a particular div in a full screen mode like as youtube when page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the below code but this is working only on event trigger. like on button click but i want to trigger it when page is loaded.

```
function launchFullScreen(element) {
  if(element.requestFullScreen) {
    element.requestFullScreen();
  } else if(element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    element.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if(element.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
    element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
  }
}
```

Comment: Youtube does that on page load?

Comment: no youtube doesnot  but i wanted it to page load @wolff

Comment: AFAIK, that's not possible

Comment: any tip and tricks for this.@wolff

Answer (score 0):

you can use the page loaded even

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    launchFullScreen($("YOUR_SELECTOR"));
});
```

Comment: Needs user interraction in order to get fullscreen mode applied

Comment: he said "but i want to trigger it when page is loaded." :D

Comment: @wolff you mean to say without user interaction its not possible to open page as fullscreen?

Comment: @diptox i have use this but this not work for me $(document).ready(function()
{
    launchFullScreen($("#slider"));
});

Answer (score 0):

Then do this if you want it on load

```
document.onload=function(){
...
}
```

Comment: You can also use `window.onload`

Comment: Needs user interraction in order to get fullscreen mode applied

Comment: @A. Wolff what do you mean? That would work without user interaction.

Comment: @sourabh try it with window.onload